# Variable out of scope when entering a while loop in php

Tags: php, scope, while-loop

I have a problem when trying to populate an array in php.  It seems that once I enter a while loop with a mysql_fetch_assoc method I cannot populate my array.  I've included the code below.

`$params = $_REQUEST['params'];`

```
$arr["status"]="ok";
$projects=array();
$files=array();
$titles=array();

$query = 'SELECT p.id as pid, f.fname as name, f.title FROM proj p INNER JOIN pic f ON f.projid=p.id WHERE p.catid=\'' . $params['category'] . '\' ORDER BY p.ordr, f.ordr';

require("../php/connect.php");

//select all projects from chosen category and pics from selected projects
$proj_result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Select failed");

//populate from rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($proj_result)){  
    $projects[]=$row["pid"];
    $files[]=$row["name"];
    $titles[]=$row["title"];
}

$arr["projects"]=$projects;
$arr["files"]=$files;
$arr["titles"]=$titles;

echo json_encode($arr);
```

The result: {"status":"ok","projects":[],"files":[],"titles":[]}

Thank You.

Comment: It should, a while loop doesn't open it's own scope in PHP. Are you sure there are any rows in `$proj_result` (the commented out `mysql_num_rows()`?

Comment: So, what does `$i` do?  You're setting it to zero on every while loop iteration.

Comment: You should fix this if($i=0){ should be if($i==0){

Comment: mysql_num_rows() is something i plan to implement later (removed for now) thanks for pointing that out.  I've fixed the $i=0 to $i==0.  It is for the first run in the loop to have the thumbnail img in html that will be used for a fancy box gallery.

Comment: Try to add `var_dump(mysql_num_rows($proj_result))` after you do the query and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop doesn't create a new scope, as you can see here: http://codepad.org/H1U3wXZD
About the code itself, here's a few suggestions:

0) I would consider having a database abstraction layer ([PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) would be good enough).

1) Learn how to use [`JOIN`](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php)'s. It looks like you could fetch all the necessary information with a single query, something like:

```
    SELECT p.id, p.proj, c.id, c.fname, c.title 
      FROM proj p 
INNER JOIN pic c ON c.projid=p.id 
     WHERE catid='<your category>' 
  ORDER BY p.ordr, c.ordr
```

2) You should separate the code that gets data from the db from the code that constructs the HTML (?). Perhaps you could put that in another method. Something like:

```
if ($cmd == 'catSelect') {
    $data = getData($params['category']);

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        // process data here
    }
}
```

3) I take it you are using the generated JSON to send it via AJAX to a client. In that case, I would totally cut the fat (eg: generated markup) and send only essentials (picture id, title, fname and whatever else is essential) and generate the code on the client side. This will make your page load faster and save you and your visitors bandwidth.

Comment: it is intentional for the $i to be reset to 0 every time to generate thumbnail when returning to outer loop. Thanks for pointing out my assignment error though at the top :S I should move it to the if scope though.

Comment: @Adgezaza I see, the indentation tricked me. This is still very ugly code IMO. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I know there shouldn't be a scope issue with a while loop which is why I am stuck.  Is there any other reason why this could happen? Anything in MySql that could break the code? But I am not getting any fail select warnings like I was earlier.

Comment: oh just saw your latest response.  I will try that out.

Comment: took your advise but same problem, here is the response I get. {"status":"ok","projects":[],"files":[],"titles":[]} I've tested the statement in the back end and it seems to work fine.   Posted new code.

Answer (score 0):

my jquery/ajax client side script was not sending in category properly and therefore was no selecting any rows.

The above code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop try something like this :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($proj_result)){  
    $projects[]=$row["pid"];
    $files[]=$row["name"];
    $titles[]=$row["title"];

    echo $row["pid"]." -- ".$row["name"]." -- ".$row["title"]."\n";
}
```

Do you get anything? Once you have tried it we will take it from there. My guess is that you aren't getting any data from MySQL.